# Laravel 4: Save polymorphic relationship

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to save a polymorphic relationship in laravel and can't get it to work.  I either get this error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()` if I do `$user->provider()->save($provider)`

Or I get

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'userable_type' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into 'providers' ('user_id', 'userable_type', 'userable_id') values (16, Provider, 16))`

if I switch it around and do `$provider->user()->save($provider);` as suggested in [Call to undefined Builder::save() when saving a polymorphic relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599085/call-to-undefined-buildersave-when-saving-a-polymorphic-relationship)

From what little documentation I could find on polymorphic relationships, it seems the userable_type/id stuff goes in the parent table, and since User is my parent table, rather than Provider, the 2nd method seems to be the wrong way to do it.

At a guess I'd say the problem is with my morphTo/morphOne methods, but I've no clue how to fix them since the documentation for those methods has nothing to say about their parameters.  My provider table might be set up a bit differently from what laravel expects, since it doesn't have an incremental id field as the primary key; the primary key **is** the foreign key and is named user_id.

This is my register code:

```
public function postRegister()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $user = $this->user;
    $validator = Validator::make($input, $user::$rules);

    if($validator->passes())
    {
        $user->username = $input['username'];
        $user->email = $input['email'];
        $user->password = Hash::make($input['password']);
        $user->save();

        if($input['account_type'] == 0)
        {
            $provider = new Provider();
            $provider->user_id = $user->id;

            //$provider->user()->save($provider);
            $user->provider()->save($provider);
        }

        return 'Success';
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput($input)->withErrors($validator->messages());
    }
}
```

User model:

```
<?php

class User extends Validatable implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{
    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function userable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Provider Model:

```
<?php

class Provider extends Validatable
{
    protected $table = 'providers';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('User', 'userable');
    }
}
```

Comment: You should call it: `$provider->user()->save($user)`; this is the way i'm using daily, it's working without any problem.

Comment: Well that worked.  The other answer(s) I found on SO confused me because none of them were in english.  You can post that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call it like this:

```
$provider->user()->save($user);
```